# Maintaining state through screen rotation in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, screen-rotation

There's really no code snippet for this. I'm building an Android app in Android Studio in Kotlin with a main activity in both default portrait and lanscape modes. I'm using Android Studio auto-generated `layout\activity_main.xml` and `layout-land\activity_main.xml` layouts.

**PROBLEM:** When I rotate screens in the app, all widgets reset state. For example, I have a TextView, `tvTitle`, with a default hardcoded string, `"Hello World"`. `tvTitle` normally changed to `"News"` while using the app in portrait mode. I then switched to landscape mode and `tvTitle` reverted to it's hardcoded default string, `Hello`. How can I retain the state of the app through rotations?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes?hl=en#RetainingAnObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find the solution to your particular problem after understanding the Android mechanisms for saving the application state.

I suggest that you check out the official [guide](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states).

Answer (score 1):

Got it. The simple answer that works for me here is:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var SavedVar = "Hello"

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putString("SavedVar_KEY" ,SavedVar)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            SavedVar = savedInstanceState.getString("SavedVar_KEY")
        }
        ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: `TextView`s (and all other widgets) store their own state so you shouldn't need to do this manually. I'm guessing what's probably happening is when your `Activity` is recreated after rotation, *you're setting the contents of the `TextView` yourself* to that default value during the initial setup, overwriting the saved state. So you could just check if that `Bundle` is *null* in `onCreate` - if so, no previous state, so you can initialise everything, otherwise skip it. But honestly, a lot of the time it's a good idea to initialise everything anyway, depending on what the current state should be

Comment: Yep, I was reinitializing it `onCreate`. As you point out, the best solution seems to be initializing it in 2 different ways based on `savedInstanceState`. Thanks!